# grep multiple string from text file and export it to CSV

Tags: linux, bash, shell

i have shell script which is producing multiple output

for example

```
#/bin/bash
var1=`cat test.json | grep "test" | awk -F ' ' '{print $1}'`
var2=`cat test.json | grep -e "new" | awk -F ':' '{print$5}'`
var3=`cat test.json | grep -e "new-test" | awk -F ':' '{print$8}'`

echo $var1,var2,var3
```

output of the first var1 is

```
1 
2 
3 
4 
5
```

output of the first var2 is

```
3
4
5
6
7
```

output of the first var3 is

```
834
45
345
73
23
```

how do I create a csv file with the following format?

```
1,3,834
2,4,45
3,5,345
4,6,73
5,7,23
```

Comment: show the `test.json` using regex to parse json is not recommended.

Comment: Please replace `cat foo | grep "bar"` with `grep "bar" foo`. `cat` is for concatenation, not for printing.

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Answer (score 5):

The `paste` command is what you want, together with bash process substitutions:

```
paste -d, <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2") <(echo "$var3")
```

```
1,3,834
2,4,45
3,5,345
4,6,73
5,7,23
```

Make sure you quote the variables to maintain the newlines therein.

---

Your pipelines can be simpler: cat is unneeded, and awk can do what grep does:

```
paste -d, \
    <(awk -F ' ' '/test/     {print $1}' test.json) \
    <(awk -F ':' '/new/      {print $5}' test.json) \
    <(awk -F ':' '/new-test/ {print $8}' test.json)
```

Comment: Giving me  below                                                                                                   error new1.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
new1.sh: line 19: `paste <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2") <(echo "$var3")'

Comment: I'm specifically using bash syntax. Make sure your shebang line is `#!/bin/bash` and you are **not** invoking the script like `sh myscript.sh` but like `bash myscript.sh`